# getting weird answer about pre-increment value

Tags: pre-increment

i got final tomorrow & stuck in this question .

Let's say ( c++ )

```
x = 1;
cout << ++x + ++x; // this gives me equals to 6 !
```

isn't it suppose to be 5 ? ( 2 + 3 )
i'm lost , any help would be truly appreciated .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

It's like :

```
the first ++x = 2

so now x=2
next ++x = 3
now x=3

so out = 3 + 3 = 6
```

because you are using the same variable so it will be applied to both the x.

Comment: But when should i apply this method of calculation ?

Comment: @KokSin, you need to consider that you are using the same variable name, so if you change x anywhere it will apply where ever u used the same x in that particular scope.

Comment: the same will have different result if you use something like : ++x + ++y

Comment: No. Its a technical statement. The code's behaviour is undefined and thus cannot be reasoned about.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you see everyone's post which was posted 2 years back and give them negative votes. Doesn't matter for me, i am here for answer if i have any doubt and help someone if i could.

Comment: So now you have your answer. You know know that your post was wrong and that this code is UB. I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: No. It was me that told you that it was wrong. It seems like you are more concerned with the voting that the technical matters.

Comment: it all depends on perception, i still see it right. BTW i am not concerned with voting, i am just surprised that someone has enough time to see your old post just give a negative vote without proper explanations.

Comment: It's wrong. Perception is not part of it at all. Simple facts. It's undefined behaviour. UB. You do know what UB is right? As for proper explanations I left a comment and provided a duplicate in my close vote. Presumably you followed the link to the duplicate?